# Fazer redirecionamento pra versão mobile do site via javascript ou design responsivo, qual é a melhor opção?

Tags: php, javascript

Fazer um redirecionamento via javascript para uma versão mobile do site ou fazer um design responsivo?

Comment: Pense que se for fazer um site para cada opção terá que fazer pelo menos 4 sites (celulares, tablets, computadores e tvs), e, mesmo assim, poderá ficar ruim em alguns dispositivos, fora a duplicata de código, imagine que mesmo uma pequena alteração no backend fará com que você altere o frontend em todos os sites

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que seja melhor fazer um responsivo, assim não terá que fazer dois sites (no caso um para computador e um para mobile). E também por ter mais vantagens: usabilidade, velocidade e gerenciamento. (Ref: http://www.shapeweb.com.br/blog/2017/02/07/5-vantagens-para-ter-um-site-responsivo/)

Comment: Sugiro que coloque o conteúdo relevante do link aqui, respostas somente com links podem ser invalidadas

Comment: Vi que editou sua pergunta colocando os títulos do link e o removendo, você pode manter o link como referência, só não pode deixar sua pergunta refém do link

Comment: Ah, obrigado pela dica.